# Can't get raw_input to work on my test site

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head>";
print "<title>CGI Test</title>";
print "</head><body>";
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";

#this is my very first python attempt
name=raw_input('Enter your name : ')
print ("Hi %s, Let us be friends!" % name);

print "</body></html>";
```

So, This is my entire code. This is the very first time I am using python and don't know if I configured it correctly. I simply want a user to input their name, but I am getting no area for them to type their input.

http://rollinsfamilytree.com/scgi-bin/testerpy.py

I simply get the words "Enter your name :" and then nothing. I can't enter a name. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Do I not need to have it running in HTML to run the full script? (I'm sorry if that is such a dumb question - again, I litterlly just starting learning yesterday)

Comment: You can't use raw_input() in CGI.

Comment: Oh. how do I upload it to my site then in order to use it? Do I use apache, or something else?

Comment: all I want to do is test python on my website. I have been trying to figure this out for hours now! :(

Answer (score 5):

The trick here is that `raw_input` waits for input from Standard In (abbreviated `stdin`) - however, you don't have an interactive `stdin` in CGI (if I recall correctly, `stdin` is the request).

If you want to get input from the user over HTTP you will need to use [a HTML `form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) and get the data out when the user responds:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('name')
# Note the use of triple-quoted strings
# and `.format` rather than `%`.
# Much easier to do multi-line text this way.

print """Content-type: text/html

<html><head>
<title>CGI Test</title>
</head><body>
<p>Test page using Python</p>
<form>
<label>What is your name?
<input type="text" name="name" value="{provided_name}"></label>
</form>
Hi {provided_name}, Let us be friends!
</body></html>""".format(provided_name=name)
```

However, you will probably be better off with a lightweight framework that abstracts all of this away from you like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Ok. So, in order to use python on the web, I need to download bottle? Maybe I'm biting off more than I can chew. What is bottle? How do I get my website to act as a terminal????

Comment: @RheannaLamph - no, you don't *need* to download a web framework like Bottle - but it will make it a lot easier to deal with things later on.  You can't really get your website to act as a terminal (at least, not easily) - instead you'll be dealing with the request / response cycle where you send a page to the user, the user fills it out and sends it back to you, and *then* you act on it.

Answer (score 4):

From your post and your comments, I understand you want to have a form in which to input your name, submit it and then have "Hi , Let us be friends!" printed. If that is the case, you need to add "forms" in your code which currently you don't have. I would suggest that you check this tutorial for a good explanation on the topic:

[Learn Python The Hard Way: Getting Input From A Browser](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html)

Of course, you will need to first submit your input(this would require a refresh of the web-page) before you get the desired output. You could also look in dynamic web programming to avoid the need of webpage reload.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('name')

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head>"
print "<title>CGI Test</title>"
print "</head><body>"
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>"
print "Hi %s, Let us be friends!" % name
print "</body></html>"
```

Then access http://rollinsfamilytree.com/scgi-bin/testerpy.py?name=nobody .
(Don't omit trailing ?name=nobody)

Comment: That still doesn't fix the issue of a user inputing their name

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as you think. The web browser is not a terminal, so you cannot treat it as one. If you want to use Python on the web, you have a lot to learn; things I think you learn best by doing. Try looking into [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Or any of the [other web frameworks for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

Answer (score 1):

CGI (common gateway interface) displays text!  The stdin or terminal on the server is not opened on your browser or available via some kind of proxy.

If you want to get input and display it with CGI you have to use a two step approach

1) display a html page with a `<form>` tag that includes a `<input type="text">` and a submit button.

2) Once the form is filled in and submit pressed the input text goes back to the server and you can use it to make a second page saying "Hi %s, Let us be friends!"

If you want to do something more interactive then you'll have to use javascript and css.  The Dojo toolkit is quite easy to use

Comment: Thank you. I'm not set on using CGI. I just want my script to show up on my webpage no matter how it gets there....